# What does the user limit in Win Srv 2019 Essentials apply to, concurrent connections or existing accounts?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I have one Windows Server 2019 Essentials which logs errors and automatically shuts down because of license problems. It logs the following:

> Bei der Überprüfung der Benutzeranzahl wurde eine Bedingung in der Umgebung festgestellt, die nicht mit der Lizenzierungsrichtlinie konform ist. Der Server erfüllt nicht die Microsoft-Software-Lizenzbedingungen. Diese erlauben maximal 25 lokale Benutzerkonten. Der Computer hat 29 lokale Benutzerkonten.

Didn't install that OS in German myself, but the last sentences actually simply mean that too many accounts are CREATED. It doesn't mean that too many accounts are concurrently connecting to the server or accessing it's services. And that's the point: Many of those accounts are only special users created for backup purposes or tests or alike. They are NOT all connecting to the server concurrently, most of those won't access any file or printer services ever at all.

Reading about the user limits of that Win Server edition I had the impression that it's about concurrent usage by users, NOT the pure existence of a number of user accounts itself. [Other's](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/860077-understanding-essentials-25-user-limit?page=1#entry-4445619) explicitly wrote so as well:

> it's a 25 connected/logged in users limit.

Though, that doesn't seem to be the case and instead it seems that the number of available accounts itself, regardless of if and how they are used at all, is the limit already.

**So, what exactly does the 25 user accounts limit apply to?**

Thanks!

Comment: No, how could it? That question was closed long before Server 2019 Essentials even existed. But I see where this is going: Some people not knowing any answer to my pretty concrete question want to prevent that any useful answer will ever be documented at all. This has nothing to do with quality assurance for questions, ask Wikipedia... :-)

Comment: I believe Microsoft or the vendor that you purchased this product from would be happy to discuss the terms of using their product. Questions like this, interleaved with half-baked information from other sources, aren't constructive here.

Comment: I hope you leave a very useful comment like this one to each and every question asked here, with the small adjustment of either speaking of a vendor and it's product or some project/maintainer in case of free soft- or hardware. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer [elsewhere](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/428478/what-does-the-user-limit-in-win-srv-2019-essential.html?childToView=428687#answer-428687) which suggests what I expected already: It's really about the count of users created in this edition of Windows, regardless if or how those interact with the server:

> On a Server Essentials 2019 it is the actual user count in the active directory

That makes perfect sense with what the error message tells me. What a mess... :-) Would have been of help if MS would check this restriction when actually creating a new user instead of letting things look like all is fine, while it actually isn't. I'm not allowed to e.g. create too long usernames in the corresponding UIs as well, this restriction is not too different.